# How to handle previous interventions within the pre-period of the same time series using causalimpact?

Tags: causality, intervention-analysis, causalimpact

Below you can view the univariate sales dataset for a particular product with x3 promotional interventions/campaigns (highlighted in grey and green); each promotion campaign stretched for a length of 14 days. My main objective is to eventually measure the post-period uplift of all 3 campaigns separately, but to keep complexity at a minimum, I figured it might be better to focus this question on only analysing 1 campaign correctly and then just apply the logic to the other two campaigns afterwards. The promotion campaign I want to analyse with the `causalimpact`-library, is highlighted in green (campaign #2).

[image]

**Questions:**

1. How long should the `pre-period` and `post-period` be to analyze promo campaign #2 in the best possible way?
2. More specifically, which of the 4 options is the best to use (if at all)?

**Note that:**

- Option 1 considers shorter time-frames, but excludes possible adverse effects due to previous campaigns being run.
- If I do consider to use longer pre-period ranges (Option 3 & 4), should I include the data as is or should I recreate a baseline by handling the outliers and promo spikes the same way as for example the FB Prophet library before building a forecasting model, by either:

  - `Drop` the data for the outlier & promo campaign 1, and create a new baseline for the pre-period?
  - Set the data for the outlier & promo campaign 1 to `zero`, and create a new baseline for the pre-period?
  - Set the data for the outlier & promo campaign 1 to `none`, and create a new baseline for the pre-period?
  - Use another approach, one which I have not considered above?

Thanks in advance!